# How to force a loop to not compute for previous files?

Tags: r, for-loop

I have thousands of files (as a matrix) in two folders `MEANfiles`  and `EAN`. These files have the same dimensions

I want simply to sum up each two files and create a third one so

`File1 (first folder)+ file2(corresponding file from the second folder)=file3`

The code works fine but I noticed that the loop compute for some files and then put them in the output, then compute the same files with additional files and put all in the output, and does so…. The loop doesn't take one file by file and compute but each time it computes it come back for the previous files. This is fine if I have some files but with thousands files this is a problem!

The code:

```
 dir1<- list.files("/donne/MEANfiles", "*.bin", full.names = TRUE)

 results <- list()
for (files in seq_along(dir1)){


for (i in seq_along(results)){
}
```

Comment: What type of raster? Readable by GDAL?

Comment: Any reason why you're not using the `raster` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to loop over both lists of file names simultaneously, e.g. with `mapply`, read in the two rasters with `raster`, sum them, and spit them out again:

```
library(raster)
mapply(function(x, y) {
  z <- raster(x) + raster(y)
  writeRaster(z, file.path(outputDir, basename(x)), format='HFA')
}, dir1, dir2)
```

Here I've used `format='HFA'`, which corresponds to Erdas Imagine (I had assumed this was your raster format to begin with since you started with .img extensions). Change the format as necessary (see `?writeFormats`).

I'm not sure, but it might be faster to create `RasterStack`s of subsets of your two lists of files, sum them and write out the resulting stacks of sum rasters. Something like...

```
library(raster)
i <- rep(1:10, length.out=length(dir1)) # edit 10 to reflect your memory capacity
dir1 <- split(dir1, i)
dir2 <- split(dir2, i)
mapply(function(x, y) {
  z <- stack(x) + stack(y)
  writeRaster(z, file.path(outputDir, basename(x)), format='HFA', bylayer=TRUE)
}, dir1, dir2)
```

Comment: @hyat Don't assign `raster(x)` to `x`. If you must do what you're doing, call it something else, e.g. `rx <- raster(x) ; rx[rx>1000]<-NA; z <- rx + raster(y) +raster(y1)`. We refer to `x` later, and expect it to still be a vector of filenames.

Comment: @hyat Try `raster('C:\\Users\\stemp.bin')`. You should be able to skip all the `readBin` stuff, I think.

Comment: Well if `x` and `y` have different resolutions, you can't sum (or divide, etc.) them.